# Styles missing on Webmasters Meta - Elements not visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, css, meta

Certain styles are not displaying on Webmasters Meta. The main site is OK. Other meta sites are OK. Tried Chrome 87/Windows, Chrome on iOS, Safari on iOS.

Even the "Ask Question" button is not visible! (But I know where it should be so clicked the empty space!)

No question button:

[image: Missing question button]

Should be:

[image: Question button on ServerFault Meta]

Selected "Profile" links missing (applies also to "Activity" and "Settings"):

[image: Missing "Profile" link]

Should be:

[image: Profile link on ServerFault Meta]

Voting arrows not highlighted, having upvoted/downvoted:

[image: Voting arrow not highlighted]

Should be (from ServerFault):

[image: Voting arrow on ServerFault Meta]

Additionally (since noticed):

- The "Add Picture" button is also missing when trying to upload an image in the editor.
- The button to actually preview and post the question is missing.
- Button to save the question, having edited, is missing.
- Button to "Post Your Answer" is missing (maybe that's why there has been no response to this question - 3 weeks later!?)

**Feature request:** a "tooltip" would have been handy on these links/buttons! As it stands, the pointer changes to a "hand", indicating a clickable link/button, but there is no clue as to what it actually is unless you inspect the source code!

Seems like the CSS vars (eg. `--theme-primary-color` etc) are not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize for the delay in fixing this. In the end, it turned out that we were, in fact, missing one line of code and CSS variables weren't being generated correctly.

Thanks for the report and the diagnosis!

Comment: Thank you!   We don't use the meta site that much, but it really helps to have it working when we need it.